# External USB harddisk shows up as removable device after falling down

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive

An external Trekstor HDD (3,5") fell down and since then does not mount correctly in Windows.

Since it shows up as a removeable device instead as a harddrive, my assumption (without having seen it yet) would be that only the USB controller part could be broken.
Perhaps the actual harddrive is still intact?

One could try to place the harddrive into another compatible case. I guess even though the HDD is sold in one part, there must be actually two...

Other opinions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as this happened after it fell down, I'm guessing it's not something that has to do with the PC. Since the external drive is essentially a HDD and a case it's one or the other.  If you have another external case you can place the HDD in there and find out for sure. I'm not sure what that would do to the warranty, if it still has one. Also be prepared for a lot of disassembling; external HDD cases that come complete with a HDD tend to be built like onions around the drive.

Comment: Sorry, i was talking about the HDD's USB controller, not the PC. Thanks for your suggestion, but this is essentially what I described already in my question. correct for warranty and disassembling though..

Answer (score 2):

External hard drives are supposed to show as removeable drives.  Because they are, if they're USB mounted.  I don't understand what you think the problem is.

Comment: The problem is when trying to open the drive (i think with a macbook) it said something like "please insert media". i never saw this kind of message for a harddrive..